# SQL-Server - Bulk Insert Error 7301

Tags: sql-server, file-io, sql-server-2016, bulkinsert

Using SQL Server 2016, I am working on a legacy system that requires its nightly import to run via bulk insert. I know SSIS is a better option, but not one that's available to me.

I am uploading the file from the local machine with the following command:

```
BULK INSERT DataImports.staging_Companies
FROM 'D:\xxxxx\companies_20180802093057.txt'
WITH (BATCHSIZE = 1000
,     DATAFILETYPE = 'char'
,     FIRSTROW = 2
,     FIELDTERMINATOR = '   ' -- Tab Character here
,     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
,     ERRORFILE = 'D:\xxxxx\company_errors.txt');
```

No format file is being used, and due to our dynamic handling, we would not be able to use one. When uploading the file I am getting an error as:

> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

The general opinion on this is that there is an issue with the row/line terminators. This is not the case here. The issue seems to be around file size or number of rows. The import works fine up to 2482 rows but falls over at 2483. By moving rows around I have ruled out an error on the data itself.

Once the file size/rowcount is exceeded, the command does not run at all. I have added a trigger to the destination table and a batch size, and see results for the smaller size, and none at all for the larger size.

From this, I am wondering if there is something that causes an interruption while reading the file, and cuts it off halfway through a line? I have used and maintained this system for a while and have seen far larger files processed before in terms of both rows, and data size.

Update:

Have just transferred this file onto my local machine, and ran the import on my test db (SQL2017).  The bulk insert ran fine with no errors. My local version 14.0.1000.169, client server 13.0.1601.5.

Also tested on another 2016 Server (13.0.4474.0) and that ran fine.  Is there anything in server setup that may be causing this issue? Or even something from the main file system? Am clutching at straws now.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: This might occur because your datatypes is not long enough. Try making all nvarchar. Or i could happen because its a wrong delimiter. And where is your ROWDELIMITER?

Comment: Hi Thomas, Its not down to length of data in the fields, I've already checked.  I've also tried moving some of the lines of data around, so its not the content of the data,  The delimiters aren't the issue either otherwise it wouldn't work with lower quantities of rows.  The BULK INSERT command on SQL-SERVER doesn't have ROWDELIMITER, it has ROWTERMINATOR.  Thats set to '\n' in the command, which is interpreted as '\r\n' for carriage return/line feed.  All of which work fine, with a lower number of lines.